# What is the best strategy to increasing room score outdoors?

Tags: the-sims

So, my sims lose all of their room score when they go outside, to places such as work. What can I do to combat this problem?

This is with the original Sims game, with all of the expansions.

Comment: In a phrase: Outdoor fireplaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting a high outdoor Room score is about fixing the negatives and adding positives.

Things that lower your outdoor Room score:

- **Garbage**.  Throw it away.
- Animal (or human!) **excrement**.  Clean it up.
- **Newspapers or magazines** other than the current issue of each.  Old ones get a grayish color.  Throw them away.
- **Dead flowers**.  Replant them or just remove them.

After that, you need to improve the looks of your outdoors:

- **Plant trees or flowers**.  If you use flowers, keep them watered.
- Put in other room-improvement items such as **statues**.
- The sure-fire way: **Get a swimming pool**.  A pool can guarantee the highest possible Room score.  The score for a pool depends on the size.  If you don't get highest room score with your pool, try making it a bit larger.  There's a point when the Room score is maxed out by pool alone.  It doesn't take a very large pool; you don't have to make it cover half the lot or anything.

Answer (score 1):

You can improve it when they're on your property with things like statues and such.  Once they leave for work, though, there is no way to impact it (as far as I know).